# What is an overview of scriptures about the nature and location of The New Heaven and The New Earth that John saw in Rev 21:1?

Tags: biblical-basis, new-earth

> "Then I saw “a new heaven and a new earth,” for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea." (Rev 21:1)

The New Earth seems to be a physical entity. But does scriptural evidence to the contrary exists? If not, will the old earth be renewed? Or will there be a complete new earth located elsewhere in the universe?

Thus, what is an overview of scriptures, and/or thoughts based on certain scriptures, about the nature and location of The New Heaven and the New Earth?

The scope is mainly for Biblical references, but scriptures of the church fathers and other extra Biblical sources are welcome.

Comment: Where do you find the term new heavenly earth?   Is there also a new earthly heaven?

Comment: @Kris. Good question. it is derived from Rev 21:1, which speaks about a new heaven and a new earth. In contrast to the old earth that presently exists under the old heaven. One could also call it "the new heaven's earth".

Comment: What is an overview of the meaning of new heavens and new earth?

Comment: 45 of 46 English Bible translations on Bible Hub has "and then I saw a new heaven". Only one has "and then I saw new heavens". Thus, the majority view is "a new heaven", and the "cult view", if you like, is "new heavens". Interesting.

Comment: And none have  the term new heavenly earth

Comment: @Kris. Fair enough. Looking forward reading about that in your part contribution to the overview.

Comment: On overview answer is too much work.  Each answer is supposed to present the POV of multiple denominations.  Better to ask your question of a specific denomination?denominations  then you can compile those into your font of knowledge.

Comment: @Kris. Thx. You inspired me to rectify the question.

Comment: Im not a reputable source so I’ll refrain from answering, but just a cautionary word (for what that caution is worth) as it seems like you may be trying to establish a biblical cosmology of the new order… The caution would be not to forget the distinction between cosmology and astronomy, they are two very different things, and second, not to forget the genre of Revelation is prophetic apocalyptic, not scientific treatise.

Comment: The final note would be to consider the new heaven and earth visions in Rev in the light of OT objects (specifically the Holy of Holies and the priestly breastplate) and derive their didactic thrust from the “twists” in the descriptions.

Comment: I’ve noticed this is a definite and repeated literary device in Rev, viz. taking an established construct or object and turning it on its head in some way to emphasise a point. The MAIN point of the new heaven and earth vision then becomes the faith unity of OT and NT believers. Other aspects (e.g. cosmology) are very much secondary, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question that encompasses the entire Bible.

> Gen 1 1In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

> Revelation 21 1Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth; for the first
> heaven and the first earth passed away, and there is no longer any
> sea.

In Genesis 1:1, the MT uses  הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם   (plural)  and the LXX uses τὸν οὐρανὸν  (singular), heavens and heaven, respectively. I will argue that it is probably impossible to say exactly what will be destroyed apart from earth, but also that it doesn’t make much difference to the believers who will be living in the new earth.
Jewish tradition holds that there are 3 heavens with the first two comprising the known universe and the third being the abode of God.
The destruction of the heavens and the earth was already being predicted in the OT.

The psalmist wrote,

> 102 25 “Of old You founded the earth,
> And the heavens are the work of Your hands.
> 26“Even they will perish, but You endure;
> And all of them will wear out like a garment;
> Like clothing You will change them and they will be changed.

Isaiah also prophesied:

> 51 6 “Raise your eyes to the sky, Then look to the earth beneath; For
> the sky will vanish like smoke, And the earth will wear out like a
> garment And its inhabitants will die in the same way. But My salvation
> will be forever, And My righteousness will not fail.

In the NT, Peter uses the plural οὐρανοὶ

> 2 Pe 3  10But the day of the Lord will come like a thief, in which the
> heavens will pass away with a roar and the elements will be destroyed
> with intense heat, and the earth and its works will be burned up.

From these passages it seems that the created universe would be destroyed along with earth. The question would then be if the other worldly heaven also created by God will be destroyed.
In Luke 21,  Jesus uses ὁ οὐρανὸς in the singular. He often used terms like ”kingdom of heaven” to denote the Father’s abode, though admittedly the plural can also be used with that meaning.

> 33Heaven and earth will pass away, but My words will by no means pass
> away.

We saw that Revelation 21 refers to the first heaven and earth passing away and the same singular term οὐρανὸν also refers the heaven οὐρανοῦ from which the new earth descends.
It is therefore possible that the so-to-speak supra sidereal heaven will also be destroyed because a new earth will be created for the purpose of God being together with man. He would not then need to dwell in a heavenly abode. The description given in this verse is that there will be no sea, so it will be quite different from the water-defined world we now live in. We are not told what the purpose of a new heaven would be and it could be the new galactic environment for earth.

The early church fathers tended to interpret Revelation literally. Irenaeus  quotes Isaiah 65.

> 17“For behold, I create new heavens and a new earth;
> And the former things will not be remembered or come to mind.
> 18“But be glad and rejoice forever in what I create;
> For behold, I create Jerusalem for rejoicing
> And her people for gladness.
> 19“I will also rejoice in Jerusalem and be glad in My people;
> And there will no longer be heard in her
> The voice of weeping and the sound of crying.

He believed that the tabernacle was a type for the new Jerusalem.

> And of this tabernacle Moses received the pattern in the mount; Exodus
> 25:40 and *nothing is capable of being allegorized*, but all things are
> steadfast, and true, and substantial, having been made by God for
> righteous men's enjoyment. For as it is God truly who raises up man,
> so also does man truly rise from the dead, and not allegorically, as I
> have shown repeatedly. And as he rises actually, so also shall he be
> actually disciplined beforehand for incorruption, and shall go
> forwards and flourish in the times of the kingdom, in order that he
> may be capable of receiving the glory of the Father. Then, when all
> things are made new, he shall truly dwell in the city of God. For it
> is said, He that sits on the throne said, Behold, I make all things
> new. And the Lord says, Write all this; for these words are faithful
> and true. And He said to me, They are done. Revelation 21:5-6 And this
> is the truth of the matter. (Against Heresies (Book V, Chapter 35)

### Speculative addendum added free of charge

God destroys the earth because it has been corrupted by man’s sin. Maybe it is possible that heaven becomes corrupted by the sinners who are resurrected to receive judgment there.

> “But for the cowardly and unbelieving and abominable and murderers and
> immoral persons and sorcerers and idolaters and all liars, their part
> will be in the lake that burns with fire and brimstone, which is the
> second death.” Rev. 21:8 NASB

I realize that this is speculative but it might be an argument that annihilationists could make that everything that is not holy will be destroyed along with the first heaven and earth. The forever and ever aspect of eternal damnation would then belong to the previous order and not be carried over into the new. In other words, the second death would be even more final than the first due to the resurrection to judgment.

I must confess I like that argument because I do not understand the idea of eternal punishment. Once people have clearly and painfully understood what an awful mistake they have made, why should they need to suffer forever? I am not saying however, that it is a solid hermeneutical conclusion that anyone should count on. I wouldn’t want that on my conscience if I’m wrong.  Only God knows how everything will play out and he did warn us of eternal punishment so we must take that seriously and act accordingly.

Comment: +1. Interesting. Thanks.